# wordpress theme twentysixteen page content not Display

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress twenty sixteen theme in my project, but page content, not displaying on front site in WP-admin adds page and puts content and update my front site display code is now:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?><?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?><?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: Hi, need a little more info for a useful answer.

platform, wordpress version, possibly screenshots of your page and the options. Are you getting any error in your browser console? (F12)

Comment: hello thank you for replay i am using wordpress 4.7 version i already check F12 not getting any error

Comment: This is probably a config error. Does the content display with any other theme?

Comment: wordpress version 4.7 all theme does not display content what is the issue. i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Content not showing up can be due to a few issues, but without access to your site, it's nearly impossible to be sure.

Here are a few things to try:

1. Disable all plugins to make sure none of them are interfering with your site. If your site reappear, Deena Le them one by one to see which one is causing the problems.
2. Reset permalink in setting to "plain" to see whether you've configured your site properly
3. Your PHP version may be too low (upgrade) or the pcre.backtrack_limit is set to 100000. In order to check, create a phpinfo.php file with this

   code:

   ```
   <?php

   // Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
   phpinfo();

   ?>
   ```

And then navigate to it in your browser.

If it's low, create a php.ini file or edit the existing one and modify or add the line `pcre.backtrack_limit=1000000`

4. Check in setting->reading you're showing your latest posts (and make sure you have at least one post published (not draft). If that is the problem, and you want to show a static page, you may have a problem with the static page.
5. Make sure you have the latest version of Wordpress installed.
6. Rename your theme folder in FTP from twentysixteen to twentysixteen-temp to make sure it's not the theme.